# Error while adding PDO to my code

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have connection.php file where i am initializing PDO in the $db.
And i want to check this validation in the User.php which i include after connection.php.
but it is giving me error .

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host", $db_username,$db_password);
    echo "PDO connection object created";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

How can i validate this code by executing PDO.
How i will pass the PDO to the User Class..

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/youngib/rahul/yapi/user.php on line 41

    $sql="select * from users where email='$this->email'";
            $rs=$db->query($sql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
                $msg=geterrormsg(4);
                    //email already exist
                echo $msg= "{   'success': 'false','msg':'$msg'     ,'error_code':'4'       }";
                return false;
            }
```

Please Help.

Thanks .

Comment: Show us the code that initializes `$db`. According to what you have posted, I would expect `$db` to be a non-object. Also, consider using parameterized queries, especially since you are already using PDO.

Comment: Do you see "PDO connection object created"...?

Comment: Then try checking the scope of variable $db. Try initializing $db at the start of code or make it global (Bad practice, just to check the scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject it in to the class or make a singleton DB class like...

Injection:

```
class User
{
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(PDO $db)
  {
     $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function getDb()
  {
     return $this->db;
  }

  public function isUser($email)
  {
    $stmt = $this->getDb()->prepare('select count(email) as user_exists from users where email = :email');
    return (bool) $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email))->fetchColumn();

  }
}
```

Singleton:

```
class Database {
   protected $pdo;
   protected static $instance;

  protected function __construct($dsn, $user, $password)
  {
     $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  }

  public static function getInstance()
  {
     if(!self::$instance) 
     {
       // normally you would load the dsn, user, and password from a config file
       $db = Config::get('db');
       self::$instance = new self($db['dsn'], $db['user'], $db['password']);   
     }

     return self::$instance;
  }

  public function getDb()
  {

    return $this->pdo;
  }
}


class User
    {
      protected $db;

      public function __construct(PDO $db = null)
      {
         if(null !== $db)
         {
            $this->db = $db;
         }
      }

      public function getDb()
      {
         if(!$this->db)
         {
            $this->db = Database::getInstance()->getDb();
         }

         return $this->db;
      }

      public function isUser($email)
      {
        $stmt = $this->getDb()->prepare('select count(email) as user_exists from users where email = :email');
        return (bool) $stmt->exectute(array(':email' => $email))->fetchColumn();

      }
    }
```

Comment: please check my reply in answer

Comment: Hi ,now i am getting this error ,Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::exectute() in /var/www/youngib/rahul/yapi/user.php on line 50 on this statement     return (bool) $stmt->exectute(array(':email' => $email))->fetchColumn();

Comment: Singletons have no use in PHP. There is no shared application memory and the allowed amount of db connections can be managed from within the appropriate adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but try just adding

```
global $db;
```

before your `$db->query($sql);` line.  It might work, depending on exactly where the $db was created.

That said, prodigitalson's answer is a vastly improved approach, it just involves fixing your entire design, which involves more up front work :)